# problems with ROSARIA

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROSARIA package for use with a pioneer robot P3DX.
I am trying with two methods.

1.
***$ sudo svn co https://amor-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg/***

the response is

***svn: The server sent unexpected return value (405 Method Not Allowed)  OPTIONS for  in response to the request «https://amor-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg»***

2.
***$ sudo rosinstall /opt/ros//electric/ 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=amor-ros-pkg.rosinstall'***

the response is

***RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded***

I don't know how install ROSARIA package.
Can you help me please??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11880/problems-with-rosaria/) by [arroyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1353/arroyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I faced similar issue. It is the version control issue. I went to the link [https://amor-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg/](http://https://amor-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/hg/) and downloaded files and folders manually. And placed them in the same tree structure as given in the server and followed the rest of the process in the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA. It worked for me. Let me know if you face any issues in the process.
Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Karthik

---

**Edited on Nov 16**

To move the robot you should have the teleop_base installed. You can check the other answer that posted.
http://answers.ros.org/question/2928/require-help-using-rosaria#4674
Pls check the topics where the nodes are publishing using either

```
rostopic list
```

or

```
rxgraph
```

Thanks,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1